# Can a mutator method modify a variable/object and return it?

Tags: java

Is it okay to write a mutator method that modifies a variable/object and returns a value? For example, a function implementing a sorting algorithm that returns a sorted array?

Would this be considered a mutator method?

Comment: But if you do this the method is no longer a bean compliant mutator method. Your example however is not one of a mutator method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this isn't a common way to write a mutator, there is nothing wrong with it as long as you make it clear that you return the updated value.